# How to set a toggle as open by default in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, toggle

I'm trying to set a toggle as open by default in Vue.js, however I'm not really sure where I should use Boolean. Where should I put Boolean "true" or "false"? in Vue.js? In script tag, I'm not sure how I can write Boolean in this code.

Answer (score 1):

In data define boolean 'openMenu'

```
data: function() {
        return {
         openMenu : false,
    }
    }
```

In HTML

```
<div id="nav-content" v-show="openMenu">
```

In method toggle that using SideBarToggle function

```
methods: {
   sideBarToggle(){
     this.openMenu = !this.openMenu
    }
}
```

Or toggle from template HTML also

```
<div class="mouseover nav-toggle" @click="openMenu != openMenu">
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
I tried it and it is opened now, however it does not close now.
should I use sideBarToggle instead openMenu?